# Convergence of a series containing arithmetic mean.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to ask the following problem:

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\sum a^2_n$ converges. For $b_n = \dfrac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n }{n}$, does $\sum b^2_n$ converges?

At first, I tried to find a counterexample by computing the case where $a_n = 1/n^{1/2 + \epsilon} $, but sadly that made $\sum b^2_n$ convergent. Also, I tried to prove that the sequence converges by using C-S inequality, limit comparison test, etc... but all ideas failed.

Please give me your advice or ideas for this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should work on proving the discrete-version of hardy's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying [Hardy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality). Your case is $p = 2$ and you have $\sum b_n^2 \leq 4 \sum a_n^2$, but you already know that $\sum a_n^2$ converges. Can you work with the definition of series convergence from here?

Comment: Yes, I found that the leftover is straightforward. Thanks a lot! I'll work myself in order to prove the hardy's inequality. (not using the integrated version)